# jCarousel show arrows only when mouseover the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, mouseover, jcarousel

I'm trying to get the arrows for my jCarousel to show only when I mouse over the container (I will have multiple containers in same page)

But I have no idea how to even approach this.

Does anyone have any hints as to how this can be done?

It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have something that you already tried?

Comment: I was able to fix it using only CSS

'.jcarousel-container-horizontal:hover .jcarousel-prev'

Answer (score 0):

First you have to hide your arrows by default, so in CSS do:

```
.arrow-class {display:none;}
```

Then use jquery to show when you hover over the image

```
$(".image-class").hover(function(){
    $(".arrow-class").show(); //this happens when you mouse in
}, 
function(){
    $(".arrow-class").hide(); //this happens when you mouse out
});
```

Comment: I actually ended up doing it with CSS only.

When they hover on the container, call the button class to show it!

I appreciate the reply, though!

Comment: make sure it works in all browsers. Some other browsers only respect :hover selector on anchors (<a>)